# Kotlin Android Studio - onClickListener using apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to create a `onClickListener` eventhandler that handles a button click.
In my `articlerecycler_item` layout file I have:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSave"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:onClick="btnSave"
    android:text="@string/save"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Then in my `ArticleAdapter.kt` file I have:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): 

ArticleViewHolder {
      val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.articlerecycler_item, parent, false)
      return ArticleViewHolder(view)

      listener.setOnClickListener(this)

  }
    /** Called when the user taps the Save button  */
    override fun onClick(v: View?){
        (R.layout.articlerecycler_item)
        AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Article Saved.")
                .create()
                .show()
        // Do something in response to button click
    }
```

My question is what to use instead of `findViewById` since that is no longer needed because of the plugin: `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'`

Answer (score 0):

You can reference that view simply as `articlerecycler_item`. You only need to import it with alt + enter.

Answer (score 0):

Why make everything harder? It's much easier to use.

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener{
    // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: I've tried this way as I've found this on other threads, but it gives me an unresolved reference for `btnSave`

Comment: Will be better to read that
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html